# Define and access map field inside struct in golang?

Tags: go, struct

Suppose I have a struct named Test,

```
type Test struct {
    Value1 int `json:"value1"`
    Value2 int `json:"Value2"`
    People map[string]string `json:"Value3"`
    Timeupdate string `json:"Timeupdate"`
}
```

and people variable is a collection of key value pairs. How can I define and access people inside the struct?

```
var object = Test{Value1: arg1, Value2: arg2, People: args3, Timeupdate: time.Now().String()}
```

how can I define and access people inside this object?

Comment: Is the small p (`people` instead of `People`) intentional? This makes that the field is not accessible outside the package where `Test` is defined and will not be parsed from json. I suspect that is the root cause of this question because there is nothing special about accessing maps inside structs (`object.people["key"]` would work just fine).

Comment: That wasn't intentional (Thanks for reminding). I need clarification while declaring object what should be args3 (i.e how to define People inside object)? @VincentvanderWeele

Comment: @AshwinSekhari `args3` should be `map[string]string`, same as People field's type. Is your question on how to initiliaze a map?

Comment: @mkopriva Yes can you give an example how to initialize a map inside the object?

Comment: @AshwinSekhari Just like you would do it outside of an object. `make(map[string]string)` or `map[string]string{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could initialize an empty map:

```
args3 := map[string]string{}
```

Or a map with values:

```
args3 := map[string]string{"jane": "Jane"}
```

You can assign values later directly:

```
args3["john"] = "john"
```

Or after initializing object:

```
var object = Test{Value1: arg1, Value2: arg2, People: args3, Timeupdate: time.Now().String()}
object.People["claire"] = "Claire"
```